# Why isn't Math.nextAfter(Double.MAX_VALUE, 1) equal to Double.INFINITY?

Tags: java, floating-point

According to [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter-double-double-):

> ```
> public static double nextAfter(double start,
>                            double direction)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> - If start is equal to ± Double.MAX_VALUE and direction has a value such that the result should have a larger magnitude, an infinity with same sign as start is returned.

But according to [this example](http://ideone.com/ViXB2j):

```
System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(Math.nextAfter(Double.MAX_VALUE, 1));
System.out.println(Math.nextAfter(Double.MAX_VALUE, 1) == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

Output:

```
1.7976931348623157E308
1.7976931348623155E308
false
```

Eh? Not only is it not `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, it's actually *smaller* in magnitude.

```
...157E308
...155E308
```

Am I just completely misreading the Javadoc?

Comment: Isn't "larger magnitude" the keyword here? What I mean is that due to precision errors `Double.MAX_VALUE + 1` probably can't be represented accurately anyways and thus the result of that is `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Apparently goes into the `if (transducer > 0L) --transducer;` branch

Comment: @Thomas "and thus the result of that is " read the digits carefully. It's not the same (differ in the least significant digit).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Apparently the value is subtracted as the source says: `if (direction > start) { // Calculate next greater value ... }.  else  { // Calculate next lesser value`. This seems to indicate that since `direction` is 1 it is smaller than `MAX_VALUE` and hence the next lesser value is calculated.

Comment: Aaah, I see, it would have to be `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` as the direction parameter.

Comment: From the Javadoc (emphasis by me): "Returns the floating-point number adjacent to the first argument in the _direction_ of the second argument." As I understand it this means that if `direction` is smaller than `start` a smaller value will be calculated and thus the only valid direction for `MAX_VALUE` to be increased would be positive infinity.

Comment: Use `Math.nextUp` for the desired effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The docs are misleading.

The *direction* parameter needs to be *greater* than `Double.MAX_VALUE` for the returned value to have a *larger* result.

Since 1 is smaller, the output is the floating point number *just before* the one you provide.

The C++ docs (under IEEE754) are clearer and even spell out this edge case explicitly: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter